# How do I get the url for a Drupal image, taking into account its style?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

In a Drupal 7 .tpl.php file, given an image `$some_node->field_image`, how do I fetch the appropriate URL for use in an img src attribute, taking into account the image's style as set in its node's content type's display settings? I have seen the following suggestion, but without any indication where `$style` is coming from:

```
image_style_url($style, $some_node->field_image['und'][0]['uri']);
```

(the incumbent views are full of these `foo['und'][0]bars` by the way, is this really how it's done in Drupal, it seems ridiculous?)

Answer (score 3):

The `$style` is the style name (machine name) of the style you want to apply to the image. You can find all the image styles at `?q=admin/config/media/image-styles`.

See [image_style_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7) for more details.

Example:

```
image_style_url('large', $some_node->field_image['und'][0]['uri']);
```

### Update

Based on your last comment. I'd suggest you to use [`field_view_field`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7).

Example:

```
 $node = node_load(12);
 print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'YOUR_IMAGE_FIELD_NAME'));
```

Comment: Thank you, but I specifically do not want to apply a fixed style, I want the image to use its own style as set in its node's content type's display settings.

Comment: Thanks again, but that results in the whole pre-constructed img tag, all wrapped up in field-item divs etc, and its img src url doesn't incorporate its style anyway. I can get the img tag in divs like this and have the correct styled src url by doing: `$some_view = node_view($some_node); print render($some_view['field_image']);` but I just want the src attribute on it's own, or at a push the whole img on its own.

Comment: remove the `render()` function if you dont want the img tag.